# How to render fetched data from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I'm trying to fetch data from an API that I want to render in a table. I am following this example, and have also tried others as well:
https://blog.hellojs.org/fetching-api-data-with-react-js-460fe8bbf8f2

When I try to console.log the state I get state is undefined. When I console.log the data I receive the correct data. I know how to solve my problem with pure JavaScript, but really want to make it work this way.

```
import React from "react";
import Row from '../components/Row';

class Table extends React.Component {

constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        users: [],
    };
    this.createNewUser = this.createNewUser.bind(this);
    this.deleteExistingUser = this.deleteExistingUser.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount() {
    console.log("Component did mount!");
    fetch("http://localhost:8080/users")
        .then(response => {
            return response.json();
        }).then(data => {
        let users = data.response.map((row) => {
            return (
                <tr>
                    <td>{row.name}</td>
                    <td>{row.email}</td>
                    <td>{row.phone}</td>
                    <td>{row.age}</td>
                    <td>
                        <button className="red waves-effect waves-light btn">
                            Delete
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            );
        });
        this.setState({users: users});
        console.log("state", this.state.users);
    });
}

render() {
    return (
        <table id="" className="highlight centered">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="table_body">
            {this.state.users}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    );
}
}

export default Table;
```

Comment: `this.setState({users: users})` is asynchronous. This means that you cannot be certain that when you attempt to access `this.state` that it's the latest version of state.

Answer (score 0):

Okey, so after a little tinkering i was able to solve it.

I changed from:

```
let users = data.response.map((row) => {
        return (
            <tr>
                <td>{row.name}</td>
                <td>{row.email}</td>
                <td>{row.phone}</td>
                <td>{row.age}</td>
                <td>
                    <button className="red waves-effect waves-light btn">
                        Delete
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        );
    });
```

to:

```
let users = data.map((row) => {
    return <Row key={row.email} name={row.name} email={row.email}
            phone={row.phone} age={row.age}/>
});
```

Comment: it looks like the problem was where you had `data.response.map`, and you needed `data.map` because of how your response is configured. I bet it would still work with the original example by only changing that one part, but also I'm guessing you want to use your Row component and you only wrote the <tr><td> bit explicitly to debug the issue...

Comment: Correct! @JSONaLeo